# Raspberry + Eclipse , How to setup remote project?

Tags: eclipse

Here is my setup with PC(Win10,Eclipse) + Raspberry Pi.

1. first, I connect Eclipse remote system with Raspberry Pi via LAN network.
2. I specify a folder of Raspberry system as "create remote project".

and Now, I can see this in my Eclipse project.

[image]

my problem is here...

1) in folder, src/com/lapis_semi/lazurite/io
   there is lot of class.

2) in folder, src/taroumaru/ 
   this is my file.

Quesiton 1:
How to "link" all class in (1) when I write (2) ?
Now, Eclipse do not know how to complete class method..

Question 2:
I create "remote project", but I do not know eclipse know all files to link... ? ( Sorry, I do not understand how eclipse should work and setup.. )